# Size of perticular rows of table which satisfy condition

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT (data_length)'Size' 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_name='abc'
```

This is giving me total data size of table "abc".
But I want data size of particular rows which satisfy condition in where clause.

Say,

```
SELECT (data_length)'Size' 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_name='abc'
and abc.id=1
```

So,I want data_length of rows which satisfies this condition,but above not working.

I guess you understand my query.

Comment: do you want the number of bytes it takes to store these records on disk? or the number of bytes you would get back if you were to return all the rows?

Comment: @Randy,I want size on disk